# Is PGP encryption supported in AWS KMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, pgp

I see that the two asymmetrical format supported by AWS is RSA and ECC. I do not see any reference for PGP format. Is there a way to create PGP keys in AWS?

Link to the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/symm-asymm-concepts.html#asymmetric-cmks

Comment: Based on that reference, there is no support for PGP. I use KMS, and have never come across any reference for PGP.

Comment: Curious why do you need PGP keys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on that reference, there is no support for PGP. I use KMS, and have never come across any reference for PGP support.